# Spring batch MongoItemReader ignoring database index (created via Spring Data)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-batch, mongodb-indexes

I'm getting the following whenever I fire off a job,

> database error: Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554495 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes

I know why this is, I also know how to increase that value but I'd rather use a index as suggested instead.

I've attempted to set an index but it seems to not work. All I've done is modified my POJO as such

```
@Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING)
String creationTime;
```

And then in my `MongoItemReader`

```
reader.setQuery(new Query().with(Sort.by(Order.desc("creationTime"))));
```

However that hasn't made a difference, is there more I need to do to enable that index?

Comment: In MongoDB dates are stored in ms since Jan 1, 1970, so there is no difference in indexing

Comment: Good to know, but that doesn't really help me as I'm dealing with a string.

Comment: What makes you say that the mongo item reader is ignoring this index? Have you tried to read data from mongo with a mongoTemplate before using the Spring Batch reader? Do you have the issue using directly the mongoTemplate?